# Is there a simple way to send out notifications whenever a file/folder is modified in Google Drive?

Tags: notifications, google-drive

I've got a Google Drive account that multiple people on different devices may be using, so that I can simply upload a file and have them be able to access it right away. Is there a way I can get Drive to send out notifications to logged-in devices whenever a file is uploaded? Whether that be through the Drive app (most people will be using smartphones), SMS or whatever doesn't matter, as long as it immediately shows up on their device (I'm trying to avoid using email for this very reason).

Comment: There is no way to subscribe to a file or folder on Google Drive at this time.

Comment: You could do something with IFTTT that triggers when a new file is uploaded, but it's not designed for group notifications. It's really only made to work for a single person.